# Access the variable value using the variable name string - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I have:

```
var red = ["#F33121", "#F06562", "#90A4AE"]; //my array called red.
var blue = ["#345678", "#234423", "#435223"]; //my array called blue.
var color = $('.element').text(); // = red
```

So now, `console.log(color);` returns `red`.

How can I get

`console.log(color[0])` to return the contents of `red[0]`?

Sorry if it doesn't make sense, I can't think of a simpler way to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bad practice:**

If the arrays are global variables you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) with [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object to access the array.

```
window[color][0]
```

```js
var red = ["#F33121", "#F06562", "#90A4AE"]; //my array called red.
var blue = ["#345678", "#234423", "#435223"]; //my array called blue.


$('input').on('keyup', function() {
  var color = $.trim($(this).val());

  $('pre').html(window[color] ? JSON.stringify(window[color], 0, 4) : 'No color found');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />

<pre></pre>
```

**Better alternative:**

Use the object to store the key-value pair as follow:

```
var colors = {
    red: ["#F33121", "#F06562", "#90A4AE"],
    blue: ["#345678", "#234423", "#435223"]
};
```

and access the array using

```
colors[color]
```

```js
var colors = {
  red: ["#F33121", "#F06562", "#90A4AE"],
  blue: ["#345678", "#234423", "#435223"]
};

$('input').on('keyup', function() {
  var color = $.trim($(this).val());
  $('pre').html(colors[color] ? JSON.stringify(colors[color], 0, 4) : 'No color found');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />

<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If provided code is under the global `context`(window), you can access property of the `window` object using `[]` notation.

I suggest you to have `object` of arrays like `var obj = {red:[...],blue:[...]  }` so that you can easily access the key of the object.

Try this:

```js
var red = ["#F33121", "#F06562", "#90A4AE"];
var blue = ["#345678", "#234423", "#435223"];
var color = 'red'
console.log(window[color][0]);//will not work if variables are local and do not belong to `window`
```

Using object:

```js
(function() {
  var input = {
    red: ["#F33121", "#F06562", "#90A4AE"],
    blue: ["#345678", "#234423", "#435223"]
  }
  var color = 'red'
  console.log(input[color][0]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to be an object and you can just use bracket notation

```
var colors = { 
    red : ["#F33121", "#F06562", "#90A4AE"], 
    blue : ["#345678", "#234423", "#435223"]
};
var color = $('.element').text(); 
console.log(colors[color]);
```